# The system does not differentiate between text and Arduino files

Tags: 22.04, files, file-format, mime-type, arduino

I use ubuntu 22.04 LTS with Gnome 42.5 on wayland. I have installed the latest version of the Arduino IDE (an .AppImage file). My problem is that when I have to open the sketches from the file manager (I use Gnome Files) it either recognizes the .ino files as plain text files or as C source files. If I set the Arduino IDE as default to open the file .ino, then I always open all text files with Arduino.
How can I "separate" plain text files from Arduino ones (.ino extension)?

Thanks in advance for the help

### Update 29/04/2023:

What I don't understand is why some sketches are recognized as plain text files (image 1) and others as C sources (image 2), even though they both have the .ino extension. Isn't there a way to create a new mime-type category for .ino files?
I hope I explained myself better.

Image 1: [.ino file recognized as plain text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLoXs.png)

Image 2: [.ino file recognized as C sources file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEK6r.png)

### Update 30/08/2023:

I know that .ino files are actually plain text files, but I'd like to be able to create a new mime type category (I understand that on Linix files are "identified" like this)for .ino files. I found some guides on the internet, but it never worked. Actually I would need this for other programs as well. What I'm trying to do is a Windows-like solution where files are "identified" by extension.

Thank you

sim.dll

Comment: The system does not differentiate Arduino files from text files because Arduino files ARE text files. Read `man file`.

Comment: check the 1st line of the file.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, but can I create a new mime-type category for .ino files?
Thank you

Comment: Didn't answers like 636527 work for you?  Does the file ~/.config/mimeapps.list actually contain your modifications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to identify your `.ino` file MIME-type, it will probably print `text/plain` like so:

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype file.ino 
text/plain
```

... and the default application for that MIME-type will probably be some text editor like so:

```
$ xdg-mime query default text/plain
org.gnome.TextEditor.desktop
```

... So, it's doing what it's supposed to do and no wonder.

What you might actually need is to prepare that `.ino` file extension as a new [MIME-type](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/shared-mime-info-spec/) following [this tutorial](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/AddingMIMETutor/) and install it using the [`xdg-mime`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/xdg-mime.1.html) tool ... So, what you want should be something like this:

First, run:

```
cat <<'EOF' > /tmp/mime-ino.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
  <mime-type type="application/extension-ino">
         <comment xml:lang="en">.ino file</comment>
         <glob pattern="*.ino"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
EOF
```

to create it ... and then run:

```
xdg-mime install /tmp/mime-ino.xml
```

to install it ... then kill all running file-manager processes like so:

```
killall nautilus
```

Now your files with the `.ino` extension should be distinct from text files like so:

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype file.ino 
application/extension-ino
```

... but without a default application:

```
$ xdg-mime query default application/extension-ino
$
```

... and all you need to do is to click on the file and choose the default application to open it from now on ... or you can do that from the command line using this syntax:

```
xdg-mime default application mimetype
```

Comment: Your answer was correct and I granted the bounty. I was doing the last step the wrong way. Thank you very much. I'll delete this comment/answer in a few, but wanted to thank you first.

Comment: @TheImpaler You are welcome. I am glad that helped ... It might be worth noting that `xdg-mime install /tmp/mime-ino.xml` will run as `--user` and therefore install the new MIME-type for the current invoking user only ... On the other hand `sudo xdg-mime install /tmp/mime-ino.xml` will run as `--system` installing it system-wide for all users.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/defaults.list` to open the defaults configuration. From there you should be able to go to Search > Replace > Replace All and change the apps per format as you wish them to be. [This guide by libre-software.net](https://libre-software.net/linux/change-the-default-application-linux-mint-ubuntu/) goes more in depth on this topic.

Comment: The ~/.config/mimeapps.list actually has a section, [Added Associations] that have the user's choices (and a Defaults section as well).